# How can I set the browser version in Selenium RemoteWebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium

When I use `HtmlUnitDriver` I can set my own browserVersion like:

```
private HtmlUnitDriver initDriver() {
    BrowserVersion browserVersion = new BrowserVersion(
            BROWSER_NAME,
            BROWSER_OS,
            USER_AGENT,
            Float.parseFloat(BROWSER_VERSION));
    browserVersion.setBrowserLanguage(BROWSER_LANGUAGE);
    browserVersion.setHtmlAcceptHeader(HTML_ACCEPT_HEADER);
    return new HtmlUnitDriver(browserVersion);
}
```

Is it possible to do the same with the `RemoteWebDriver` ?

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
            new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),
            myCapabilities);
```

In `Capabilities` I can set `myCapabilities.setBrowserName("htmlunit")`. Is that all that I can do ?

**EDIT**:

To be clear, I need 3 things:
a) Selenium-server-standalone to be able to reuse the same old SessionID
b) To make browser that works only from console (so no firefox afaik)
c) To make http requests the same as the latest browsers so there will be no difference in the server logs.

Comment: It's not clear how the points in your edit are related to the rest of the question. A little background is nice often, but in this case the main question is clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set a lot of parameters, for example:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");
capabilities.setVersion("35.0");
capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.VISTA);

try {
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.63.109:5555/wd/hub"), capabilities);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

A bit more settings to skip dialog on file downloading using custom FirefoxProfile:

```
public static WebDriver setDriver() {

     FirefoxProfile fxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();

     fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
     fxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
     fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
     fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", dir);
     fxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.ms-excel," +
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

     return new FirefoxDriver(fxProfile);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I need HtmlUnitDriver that will appear as the latest 'chrome'. I need 3 things: a) Selenium-server-standalone to be able to reuse the same SessionID  b) To make browser that works only from console (so no firefox afaik) c) To make http requests the same as the latest browsers so there will be no difference in the server logs. That's why I think that I need such thing as a BrowserVersion with RemoteWebDriver.